What is this Chinese movie about four separated siblings?
I'm trying to figure out the title of a film that was in Mandarin Chinese. It was filmed before 2006 (I think I saw it in 2006 or 2007 at the latest on VCD). There were four siblings who'd been separated for some reason. One of them is adopted by some Westerners and ends up becoming a conductor (or possibly some sort of classical musician). She travels back to China for a performance during the non-flashback portions of the film, and the siblings reunite at the end of it. 

Note: I'm not completely sure about the specific details: e.g. it's possible that the conductor ends up adopted by overseas Chinese instead.

Probably the Chinese film 'Wo de xiong di jie mei' (AKA Roots and Branches) from 2001. According to a review, it's about 4 siblings separated, and one of them becomes a famous conductor.

The Qi family was very poor but very close and happy. The fact that dad was under a political cloud (for teaching the wrong music) meant that their standard of living would never improve, and so it was doubly worrying that mum had tuberculosis. One snowy night, as Mr Qi carried his wife to the hospital, they died in an accident. Their four orphaned children ran away from unwelcoming adoptive relatives, and the elder boy Yiku found foster parents for his brother and two sisters. Twenty years on, their fates reflect precisely the homes in which they were fostered. The younger boy is a student at Dong-Bei University. The younger girl is a drop-out, hanging with a rough crowd. Yiku is a taxi-driver in Beijing. And Sitian, the elder girl, is an American-educated orchestra conductor coming home to give her first concert in China. Her ulterior motive, of course, is to track down her long-lost siblings... 


